# Cross sections of randomly distributed defects

Tags: cross-sections

A $10 \times 10 \times 10$ mm cube has $1000000$ 2-micron spheres randomly distributed thru out it.  If a random cross-section was done. What would be the area of the cross-sectioned spheres and how many portions of spheres could be counted?

Comment: Is 2-micron the radius or the diameter of the sphere? Is a cross-section found intersecting a random plane and the cube?

Comment: The odds that a random chord in a unit circle has length less than sqrt(3) is either 1/2, 1/3, or 1/4, as shown in the [random chord paradox](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RandomChordParadox/).  The random cross section is worse.

Comment: @EdPegg For that paradox it is a matter of choosing the method for drawing the chords. By the way I think the "random cross section" calculus could be simplified observing that any area obtained by the intersecting a plane and a sphere (provided this is the method intended) is a circle whose radius can be desumed from the distance between the section and the center of the sphere.

Comment: Lets say it's the radius

Comment: @JamesS It would be helpful if you defined how a "random cross-section" was done. As Ed Pegg noted, different ways in cutting the cube could yield different values for the probability of what you're asking.

Comment: If the spheres are randomly dispersed, wouldn't the count at any one cross section be more or less the same?

Comment: Let me put out the real life problem:  I work in the metals business and inclusions(oxides) are not a good thing normally.  We took cross sections of ingots, polished and had them scanned for inclusions.  The gave us the total count of inclusions, the area scanned and the %area covered by inclusions.  I would like to determine the volume of the inclusions so that I can back calculate the weight and knowing what type of oxide it is I can then call the wt% of oxygen.  The inclusions are globular and randomly dispersed and relatively the same size.